# How to write a .SVG to pdf with PdfSharp

Tags: c#, svg, pdfsharp

I'm using PdfSharp and saving .png files. It works fine. Now I need to save SVG images and I'm getting an error

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.
```

The code is

```
var path = @"D:\Projects\ProjectName\Content\Images\Instruments";
path += Path.GetFileName(instrument.Src); //instrument.src is a valid name and the path is a valid path on the local machine, which is where I'm testing

if (!File.Exists(path))
    return;  //never hit as the path is correct

var img = XImage.FromFile(path); //out of memory
//more code
```

If I change the above from .svg to .png it works fine (since I have both, a .png and .svg file with the same name)

How can I save the SVG image to PDF using PDF Sharp?

Comment: change your code and wrap all necessary objects around a `using(){ }` construct. also you are returning `outputPdf` is that a string or an actual pdf? you need to dispose of other newly created objects also before returning out of the method. At what point do you get the error..? running first time..? or running multiple times..?

Comment: show us what the value of the directory is when you use the debugger please for this value `inputSvg` also does your application have access to your Special folders vs you navigating to the folder path manually..?

Comment: Check this link out too http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PageSizes-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: try writing to a different directory like `"c:\tempPdf\"`

Comment: the link you have provided does not provide a solution so if you copied and pasted the code.. you are pasting broken code.. nowhere was an accepted answer posted on the link in your post.. however the last post does talk about this as an option http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: this sounds like a bug if it works for all other types.. perhaps you can convert the .SVG type to a jpg or png otherwise it appears you are out of luck until this bug has been fixed.. your code however does work fine as is as long as no .SVG is being used..what if you try `ITextSharp` it's a free dll wonder if it works using that instead

Comment: Do you use pdfsharp? It doesn't seem like it

Answer (score 8):

PDFsharp supports raster images like PNG and JPEG. Vector images like SVG are not yet supported. This is not a bug, this is an implementation restriction. Pages from PDF files can be used like images and allow using vector images with PDFsharp.

`XImage.FromFile` passes the image to either GDI+ or WPF (depending on the build you are using) and expects to get a raster image in return. I do not know what GDI+ or WPF return for SVG images.

If you find source code that draws SVG images using a `Graphics` object then you can easily adopt that for PDFsharp's `XGraphics` object.

Or try to find a library that converts SVG to raster images or PDF files.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows:

- Step 1: open your vector image in Inkscape
- Step 2: save the image in Inkscape as pdf file
- Step 3: import this new pdf file in your pdf document like this:

```c#
using (var doc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument())
{
    var page = doc.AddPage();
    using (var gr = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append))
    {
        using (var imgForm = PdfSharp.Drawing.XPdfForm.FromFile("fileWithVectorImage.pdf"))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(imgForm, new PdfSharp.Drawing.XPoint(10, 10));
        }

        //other pdf stuff with gr.DrawString etc.
    }
    doc.Save("resultPdfFile.pdf");
}
```